# Compiling Asterisk on Debian: Cannot Find `ptlib-config`

Tags: debian, configure, asterisk

My Asterisk `./configure` is returning:

```
checking /root/pwlib/include/ptlib.h usability... no
checking /root/pwlib/include/ptlib.h presence... no
checking for /root/pwlib/include/ptlib.h... no
checking /usr/local/include/ptlib.h usability... no
checking /usr/local/include/ptlib.h presence... no
checking for /usr/local/include/ptlib.h... no
checking /usr/include/ptlib.h usability... yes
checking /usr/include/ptlib.h presence... yes
checking for /usr/include/ptlib.h... yes
checking for ptlib-config... no
./configure: line 27253: --ldflags: command not found
Cannot find ptlib-config - please install and try again
```

However I clearly have `ptlib-dev` installed:

```
# dpkg --list libpt*
ii  libpt-dbg                            2.10.4~dfsg-1
ii  libpt-dev                            2.10.4~dfsg-1
ii  libpt-doc                            2.10.4~dfsg-1
ii  libpt2.10.4                          2.10.4~dfsg-1
ii  libpth20                             2.0.7-16
ii  libpthread-stubs0:amd64              0.3-3
ii  libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64          0.3-3
```

Comment: Why not use a binary package? If necessary, you could probably use a backport.

Comment: FWIW I get the same error on Ubuntu 12.04 (libpt-dev 2.10.2~dfsg-0ubuntu1); however replacing package `libpt-dev` by `libpt-1.10.10-dev` appears to allow it to configure successfully. I do not know enough about either `libpt` or `asterisk` to say whether this is a valid solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
install libpt-dev

export PTLIB_CONFIG=/usr/share/ptlib/make/ptlib-config

./configure

make
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the apt-file tool to determine which packages contain a given filename:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
...
$ sudo apt-file update
...
$ apt-file search ptlib-config
libpt-dev: /usr/share/ptlib/make/ptlib-config
```

You should also be able to retrieve all of the build-time dependencies for a given package by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep $PACKAGE # where PACKAGE=asterisk in this case
```

Comment: I tried all that. Installed all the build-time dependencies and searched with apt-file.  The thing IS installed just like in your example, but the problem persists.  I don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, set this before you run `./configure`:

```
export PTLIB_CONFIG=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

Anf then:

```
./configure
```

Comment: Thank you, on CentOS 6.8 helped `export PTLIB_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pkg-config` here.

Answer (score -1):

```
install libpt-dev

export PTLIB_CONFIG=/usr/share/ptlib/make/ptlib-config

./configure
```

Comment: The `install` command you've given will fail because your syntax is invalid. (`install: missing destination file operand after 'libpt-dev'`)